# How do I add a 'click' function to this jQuery function?

Tags: jquery, function, click

My jQuery swaps the bubble to a more colorful graphic on hover, but I can't figure out how to add a 'clicked' feature to highlight the bubble the user has chosen. If a person clicks on one of the bubbles, it should stay in that colorful hover graphic. Does this make sense?

My HTML has 4 images setup to work as in-page navigation. They are graphic bubbles. I gave each bubble it's own ID.

```js
$( ".WORLD-BTNS" ).hover(
  function() {
     var id = $(this).attr('id');
    $(this).attr("src","images/buttons/" + id + "-BTN-HOVER.png");
  }, function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    $(this).attr("src","images/buttons/" + id + "-BTN.png");
  }
)
```

```html
<img class="WORLD-BTNS" id="COLOR"  src="images/buttons/COLOR-BTN.png" />
<img class="WORLD-BTNS" id="SKINCARE" src="images/buttons/SKINCARE-BTN.png" />
<img class="WORLD-BTNS" id="FRAGRANCE" src="images/buttons/FRAGRANCE-BTN.png" />
<img class="WORLD-BTNS" id="HAIRCARE" src="images/buttons/HAIRCARE-BTN.png" />
```

[VIEW THE COLOR BTN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WSxYh.png)

[VIEW THE COLOR BTN HOVER](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZnK3d.png)

Answer (score 1):

You could solve this by having your click handler add a class to the element in question, then having your hover function exclude elements with that class.

Something like this should work:

```js
$('.some-container')
.on('mouseover', '.WORLD-BTNS:not(.selected)', function() {
    this.src = 'http://via.placeholder.com/100x100?text='+this.id+' hovered';
})
.on('mouseleave', '.WORLD-BTNS:not(.selected)', function() {
    this.src = 'http://via.placeholder.com/100x100?text='+this.id+' normal';    
})
.on('click','.WORLD-BTNS:not(.selected)',function() {
    var $this=$(this);
    $(".WORLD-BTNS.selected")
    .attr('src', 'http://via.placeholder.com/100x100?text='+this.id+' normal')
    .removeClass('selected'); 
    $this.addClass('selected'); 
    this.src = 'http://via.placeholder.com/100x100?text='+this.id+' selected';    
});
```

```css
img{
  margin:10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="some-container">
<img class="WORLD-BTNS" id="COLOR"  src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100?text=normal" data-alt-src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100?text=selected"/>
<img class="WORLD-BTNS" id="SKINCARE" src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100?text=normal" data-alt-src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100?text=selected" />
<img class="WORLD-BTNS" id="FRAGRANCE" src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100?text=normal" data-alt-src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100?text=selected" />
<img class="WORLD-BTNS" id="HAIRCARE" src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100?text=normal" data-alt-src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100?text=selected" />
</div>
```

Comment: It still doesn't work... 

I copied and pasted your code over my old code... Again, the hover works fine, but the bubble isn't staying colorful when clicked.

Comment: @Matie ah sorry, see my update above. We need to use `.on()` for the effect we want here

Comment: Now the hover doesn't work but the clicked works for all the buttons at the same time.

Comment: Do you have links for the images you're using, hard to test without them but we're almost there

Comment: @Matie , please see my update, that should get you pretty close to what you need with maybe a few tweaks

Answer (score 0):

This is working perfectly, Test it and reply to me please:

```
    $("document").ready(function(){
    sessionStorage.clear();
    $( ".WORLD-BTNS" ).on("click", function() {
        var ai= $(".WORLD-BTNS").length;
        for (var i=0 ; i<ai ; i++) {// Clear anyone clicked before. 
            $(".WORLD-BTNS").eq(i).attr("src", "images/buttons/" 
                + $(".WORLD-BTNS").eq(i).attr("id") + "-BTN.png");
        }

        var id =  $(this).attr('id') ;
        $(this).attr("src", "images/buttons/" + id + "-BTN-HOVER.png");
        sessionStorage.setItem("clicked",id);
    });

    $(".WORLD-BTNS").hover(function () {// Hover effects.
          var id =  $(this).attr('id') ;
            $(this).attr("src", "images/buttons/" + id + "-BTN-HOVER.png");
    } , function () {
          var id =  $(this).attr('id') ;
          if(sessionStorage.getItem("clicked")!=id)
                $(this).attr("src", "images/buttons/" + id + "-BTN.png");
    });
});

<html>
<img class="WORLD-BTNS" id="COLOR"  src="images/buttons/COLOR-BTN.png" />
<img class="WORLD-BTNS" id="SKINCARE" src="images/buttons/SKINCARE-BTN.png" />
<img class="WORLD-BTNS" id="FRAGRANCE" src="images/buttons/FRAGRANCE-BTN.png" />
<img class="WORLD-BTNS" id="HAIRCARE" src="images/buttons/HAIRCARE-BTN.png" />
```

PS. The idea; to keep the Clicked item ID for later check and i advice to use "sessionStorage" as previous example, and